# Combining two image into one new image in react native

Tags: android, image, react-native, merge, combinations

I have two separate images one is the main image that clicks from the camera and another image I am picking from gallery its a logo, I need to combine these two images and make new image so that I can save that image into gallery and share on social media I need to do this with react native thanks for the help

```
<Image
    style={{width: width, height: height*.7}}
    source={{ uri: imageAdress }} />
<Image 
   source={this.state.avatarSource} 
   style={{width: 80, height: 80, position:'absolute', top: 20, left: 20}} />
```

Here are the two images now i need to combine them.

Answer (score 5):

i have fount the answer of my question. You can take a snapshot of you View its simple you can put both images in one View and snapshot that View. i use this plugin.

react-native-view-shot

> https://github.com/gre/react-native-view-shot

this will allow you to take a snapshot of particular View 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use [react-native-image-tools](https://github.com/wowmaking/react-native-image-tools#mergeimages), example:

```
RNImageTools.merge(
    [
        image1,
        image2,
        image3,
    ]
).then(({ uri, width, height }) => {
  // Sync with your app state
}).catch(console.error);
```

Comment: Thank you this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
react-native-images-combine
```

https://github.com/maurisdev/react-native-images-combine

```
import ImagesCombineLibrary from 'react-native-images-combine';

ImagesCombineLibrary.combineImages([
  Image.resolveAssetSource(require('../images/test1.png')),
  Image.resolveAssetSource(require('../images/test2.png'))
]).then((base64) => {

});
```